# Why is Svelte's bind:innerHTML retaining an outdated string?

Tags: javascript, svelte, innerhtml

#### Content is displaying correctly, bind:innerHTML isn't tracking changes

The content of a div containing two `{#each}` blocks is bound to a variable via `bind:innerHTML`. These `{#each}` blocks are responsive to user input and dynamically render according to variable changes; this is already functional and the component itself displays changes correctly.

However, the variable (`svgDivContentString`) does not update as the contents of the component change. It simply retains the initial information from when the component was first mounted. No matter how the contents vary, it goes unchanged. Even if it's emptied manually via `svgDivContentString = ""`, it just resets to the default info when the `{#each}` block triggers again (regardless of what's actually being displayed). The string is needed for conversion to base64 for use as an `img.src`.

```html
<div
bind:innerHTML={svgDivContentString}
contenteditable
id="kbContainer"
>
    <svg
    id="svgContainer"
    viewBox="0 0 {$width} {height}"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    >
    {#each allNotes as note, index (index)}
        ...
    {/each}
```

#### Attempted solutions/workarounds

I tried emptying the string manually (as seen above) and ensuring that only new information was being introduced, but somehow the same default info ends up in the string every time. I have also tried going a "less Svelte" way and just using `document.getElementById` on the div, but that returns `undefined`. It's also "not very Svelte," which is often said in response to attempted JS workarounds for Svelte problems on SO posts.

Would like to reiterate that **it is not a problem with the** `{#each}` **block.** The rendered content is correctly updated every time. The problem is that `bind:innerHTML` isn't getting that memo for some reason.

Any guidance here or proposals for alternative means to the same end would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? You mix generated content (`#each`) into something that is editable; this cannot go well, _something_ will go out of sync.

Comment: @brunnerh I'm attempting to convert the contents of the div to a base64 URL for use elsewhere in my app. Would you mind explaining what you mean by mixing generated content with something editable? It sounds like I'm missing a big piece here.

Comment: The reason the contenteditable attribute is there is to enable bind:innerHTML. If it's removed I get this error: 'contenteditable' attribute is required for textContent, innerHTML and innerText two-way bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to read the HTML, you don't necessarily need to do it this way.

The reason why `contenteditable` is required for the binding, is that all bindings rely on certain events to fire which then trigger the bound variable to be updated. Unless the there is `contenteditable` there will be no editing and no editing means no `input` events.

Generally when you need to access the DOM directly, the first thing to consider is an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#use-action), this gives you a reference to the node and it executes on the creation of the element.

If you need a more persistent reference, you can use [`bind:this`](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#bind-this) on the element instead. This sounds like an application for that. Then whenever you need to read the HTML of the element you will have a local DOM element reference.

To trigger your logic, you will need to rely on other events or use reactive statements that depend on whatever is added to that element.

E.g.

```js
let container; // bind:this variable
$: if (container) {
  allNotes; // dependency
  const html = container.innerHTML;
  // [do something with it]
}
```

Comment: Using `bind:this={}` on the containing div and relying on the contents of that local DOM element reference fixed things right up; that reference stays up to date perfectly. I was sure I had tried this, but I must've done something wrong in my attempt. Thank you.